# Find subsequent commands in history

Tags: bash

To get a list of all previous `ssh` commands I can type:

```
$ history | grep ssh

1234 ssh x@y.z
1235 ssh y@z.a
1236 ssh z@a.b
…
```

But I am searching for a way to get a list all `ssh` commands followed by a `rsync` command. So the result should look like that:

```
1234 ssh x@y.z
1235 rsync y@z.de …
…
4321 ssh y@z.a
4322 rsync z@a.b …
```

So I am basically trying to find subsequent words in subsequent lines…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use:

```
history | grep -A 1 ssh | grep -B 1 rsync
```

which is non optimal because it will match cases in which you ran rsync and ssh in the same line.

The you can try better:

```
history | cut -c 8- | grep -A 1 ^ssh | grep -B 1 ^rsync
```

Here I am using history command as you were doing (because another alternative would have been to use the history file).

Then I remove the line numbers with the `cut`. (This can be not very elegant because considers that always there are 8 characters the the column of the line number in the history output, you might have to check if 8 is the right number (for the versions I can check, it is :) )).

And then I `grep` lines that start (`^`) with ssh and I ask to print that line and one line after (`-A 1`)

And then I `grep` for lines that start (`^`) with rsync an I print those lines the the previous one (`-B 1`)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The second one works like an logical or… `ssh|rsync` so that gives way too much results… The first one seams to work fine

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it there, the second option was not correct. I added a way to check only for the lines starting with ssh or rsync. I hope it is more clear.

Comment: Thanks! I like it ;)